# Taxonomy archive page have no post

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy with posts assigned to terms,
and on the term archive page i get no found post

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'mytax',
    'with_front'                 => true,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
```

and in my post list in admin, i get the same error when i filter by terms by clicking on the term in the post list
i have no error,
how i can proceed ?
thanks in advanced

**EDIT**

i try to run the wp_query request ( `wp_query->request` ) in MySQL and it's returned the correct posts,
 but the `wp_query->posts` is empty

**EDIT 2**

i try to add a new taxonomy ,
add a term to this taxonomy and add a post with this taxonomy, but the taxonomy leave after update the post

Comment: What does the archive page code look like?

Comment: the most simple loop

Comment: With the debug bar i got this
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS xxx_3_posts.ID FROM xxx_3_posts INNER JOIN xxx_3_term_relationships ON (xxx_3_posts.ID = xxx_3_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( xxx_3_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 10
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be correct.

Here is the process to debug it:

- As your code is correct (what I can see), you need to update your htaccess. To perform it, go to the permalinks WP section and save again permalinks (keep your structure).
- If not working, you need to flush rewrite rules on your function.php template
- If not working, you need to check the name of your custom template
- If not working, you need to remove your query variable with static variables (to find the if this is a template issue - wp template condition as been tested before)
- If not working, from an empty project, add you CPT an CT to review if there is any problem with plug-in etc
- If not working, send me a link to your staging server, I will find the issue in less than 5 min.

Hope this help

Comment: it's not a frontend bug

Comment: All tasks describe above are purely back-end. After reading again your question, what you need to do is to chek your label variable. Only simple character will be accepted (no space, ' " ). It might be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,
it's due to feedwordpress,
i solved it by turn off `Optimize IN clauses`
thanks for your help